# Unlinked kegs in cellar when trying to brew install watchman

Tags: homebrew, watchman

I'm trying to install watchman via Homebrew.

When it's trying to install one of its dependencies, I get this error:

```
==> Installing watchman dependency: python@2
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python@2-2.7.14_3.high_sierra.bottle.2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring python@2-2.7.14_3.high_sierra.bottle.2.tar.gz
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

Running `brew doctor` gives me:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python@2
  gnupg

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/electron
```

When I try `brew link --overwrite python@2` I get:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

And when I try `brew remove python@2` I get:

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3
because it is required by mongodb, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@2
```

I'm a bit lost here as I have little to no experience using brew. I just want to get watchman installed!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like brew was trying to link `python@2` but couldn't because it couldn't make the folder `/usr/local/Frameworks`.

This was solved with the following steps:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/Frameworks
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
brew link python@2
```